Ubuntu installation 22.04 - surface pro 8
I have installed 22.04 but due to some technical issue I deleted the Ubuntu partition from my windows and its grub file. Once again, I created a bootable USB using rufus 4.5. I inserted the pen drive and opened the uefi, disabled the secure boot and booted from my USB but microsoft logo appeared but not the grub of ubuntu. I am using Microsoft Surface Pro 8. I contacted the Microsoft but they couldn't able to solve it. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

If the Microsoft logo appeared, then either you didn't truly boot from the USB or your install USB was mis-made. There is no such application as "roofers," so pay close attention to detail as you check your BIOS settings and/or re-make the install USB.

I used the same bootable device to install ubuntu on my other device.
